# How would I make a ViewModel that displays a list of categories gathered from a list of products that was generated on another entity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, viewmodel, lazy-loading

- I have various `locations` that each have their own lists of `Products`.
- Each `Product` belongs to a `SubCategory`.
- Each `SubCategory` belongs to a `Category`.

I need to display a list of `Categories` when given a `Location`, so I need a ViewModel that can extract the list of potential Categories that would be associated with the Products at said Location.

I'm wanting to do something like this (my ViewModel):

```
public class LocationSummaryViewModel
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    private ICollection<Category> categories;

    public ICollection<Category> Categories
    {
        get
        {
            if ( Establishment != null )
            {
                foreach (var item in Location.Products)
                {
                    categories.Add(item.SubCategory.Category);
                }
                return categories;
            }
            else
            {
                Categories.Add(new Category { Name = "Default Category" });
                return categories;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work syntactically  because `categories` is never instantiated.  Also, I'm not sure if I should be putting this much logic in a ViewModel.

**Am I heading the right direction by putting the logic to draw Category information from a list of Products contained within a Location inside of my ViewModel?  or am I going about this in a very unusual way?**

*If I'm doing this in a completely odd way, what is a better method to get Category information from a list of Products contained within a Location entity?*

---

For reference, my Location Model:

```
public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }  
}
```

my Product Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCategory SubCategory { get; set; }

    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

and my SubCategory Model:

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int SubCategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

**Update: I have posted a potential answer to my own question below - better answers / suggestions are welcome**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The business logic should not be in view model, instead, it should be in domain model, why don't you try to move your business logic into your domain model like Location. If not, you are violating the [Anemic model anti-pattern](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html)

View Model should contain logic which support for View and nothing more.

Don't actually know Establishment comes from, but Location class might look like:

```
public class Location
{
    public int EstablishmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Category GetCategories()
    {
        foreach (var item in Location.Products)
        {
            categories.Add(item.SubCategory.Category);
        }
        return categories;
    }
}
```

Comment: Establishment was a remainder from a copy/paste (my actual variables have different names than I used in the question above).

Comment: I was able to eliminate the ViewModel entirely and just reference the Location entity within the view using your method.  Also lead to a cleaner controller.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I change my ViewModel to:

```
public class LocationSummaryViewModel
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and move my logic to the controller:

```
public PartialViewResult _LocationSummary(int id)
{
    Location location = _locationRepository.Locations.FirstOrDefault(p => p.LocationId == id);
    if (location != null)
    {
        var Categories = location.Products.Select(item => item.SubCategory.Category).Distinct().ToList();

        var model = new LocationSummaryViewModel
            {
                Location = location,
                Categories = Categories
            };
        return PartialView(model);
. . .
```

I seem to get a suitable result <strike>(few tweaks are needed to get rid of multiple identical `Categories`)</strike>, but I was hoping to find a way to get rid of the logic within my controller.

This may cause issues because of the large amount of lazy-loading required for things to work. . .  not sure at this point.